# External Test Functions (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have a method I am writing in `test_helper.rb` to simplify some bulk testing for HTML elements. While I am experimentally developing this function now, I would like to spin it off into its own stand-alone function. If this were application code, it would go in `lib/` (I think?), but since it is test code, where would I put it? Is there an location for external code for tests or would I just create a new file/directory to hold my re-usable code and `require` it inside `test_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in `test/support`, for example:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/test/support
- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/tree/master/test/support

But of course it's ultimately up to you and your project's needs.

Comment: Is `test/support` a standard location for external "libraries" (for lack of better term)? Is there a standard for this, or is it too uncommon an issue to have a standard?

Comment: I don't think you'll find one universally accepted standard for this, but that's not unusual in RailsWorld. That's why it ultimately comes down to your own sense as a developer of where something should live in your project (as it should be). The examples are from large, well-known projects. Bundler would be another, and appears to use a similar scheme: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/tree/master/spec/support.

Comment: And is `test/support/` automatically loaded for all tests? With a quick look, I didn't see any `require` lines loading it.

Comment: That can be managed from your helper, as in: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb#L26 or https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb#L35.

Comment: I have seen `test/support` and `test/shared`. The name of the folder is not important. It is important to be in the test folder, because it has nothing to do with the app; it is only for the tests. You can load the file(s) from the spec_helper.